# Missing separate debuginfo for

Tags: gdb, opensuse

I try to use gdb to debug code with coredump, but I met:

```
Missing separate debuginfo for /lib/libc.so.6
Try: zypper install -C "debuginfo(build-id)=c4b9060b36834391b7b73976d38302a7584ae40e"
Missing separate debuginfo for /lib/ld-linux.so.2
Try: zypper install -C "debuginfo(build-id)=39c1043d2fcf5b72a2199cfb765d020b1faeb863"
Missing separate debuginfo for
Try: zypper install -C "debuginfo(build-id)=753a47afb9757471dc4823893adf607eb014b82f"
Missing separate debuginfo for /lib/libc.so.6
Try: zypper install -C "debuginfo(build-id)=c4b9060b36834391b7b73976d38302a7584ae40e"
Missing separate debuginfo for /lib/ld-linux.so.2
Try: zypper install -C "debuginfo(build-id)=39c1043d2fcf5b72a2199cfb765d020b1faeb863"
```

Then I installed debuginfo for glibc and update glibc to latest version, I try gdb again, it still has one information:

```
Missing separate debuginfo for 
Try: zypper install -C "debuginfo(build-id)=753a47afb9757471dc4823893adf607eb014b82f"
```

But it doesn't mention which part is missed.

**My GDB version is:**

```
-> gdb --version
GNU gdb (GDB) SUSE (7.3-41.1.2)
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "i586-suse-linux".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
```

**OS is:**

```
Linux OpenSUSE-12.1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add these repos:

http://download.opensuse.org/debug/distribution/XX/repo/oss/

http://download.opensuse.org/debug/update/XX/

Where XX is number of your OpenSUSE version.

Make sure they are active:

```
zypper lr
```

Then

```
sudo zypper in glibc-debuginfo
```

Comment: OpenSuse 42.3;
"""
zypper ar -f http://download.opensuse.org/debug/distribution/leap/42.2/repo/oss/ debug-infos2
"""
(-f autorefresh flag, alias: "debug-info2", used the repo from 42.2)
after added, runned a refresh. zypper refresh. installed version debuginfo-2.22-3.7

Answer (score 2):

Add these repositories to the Zypper repositories list:

```
sudo zypper ar -f -n "openSUSE-Debug" http://download.opensuse.org/debug/distribution/12.1/repo/oss/ repo-debug
sudo zypper ar -f -n "openSUSE-Update-Debug" http://download.opensuse.org/debug/update/12.1/ repo-debug-update
```

After this, refresh and upgrade repositories:

```
sudo zypper ref
sudo zypper dup
```

Then, if necessary (you may get a message suggesting run `zypper ps`) restart you computer and install debuginfo for gdb:

```
sudo zypper in glibc-debuginfo
```